# Getting radio-button value on a loop

Tags: javascript, html, radio-button

I am working with a javascript function which takes the value of some questions using RadioButtons of YES or NO. To get the value of one question(Q1) I do something like this:

```
for (i=0; i<document.form1.Q1.length; i++){
   if(document.form1.Q1[i].checked)
       Array[0] = document.form1.Q1[i].value;
}
```

I have to do this for every question, so the code is getting very long. So I am trying to make a function or a loop in which the name of the question is changing. My only problem is that i dont know how to use a Variable on `document.form1.VARIABLE.value`. I already tried some ways but didnt work.

Can anyone help me with this?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: What are you doing with the aux variable for each question?

Comment: @j08691 actually I use an Array, so I use 
Array[0] = document.form1.Q1[i].value;
Array[1] = document.form1.Q2[i].value;

And so on!

Comment: What do you do this for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use

```
document.forms['form-name']['radio-button-name'].value
```

and give radio button names like `que_1` `que_2` so you can change that with `i` using string concatenation

Answer (score 2):

Here's a loop that will traverse your radio buttons and build an array with the values. In the code and example, it's set for testing three questions (named Q1, Q2, and Q3). When done, the array "aux" contains the list of checked values:

```
var max = 3;
var aux = new Array();
function getCheckedValue(groupName) {
    var radios = document.getElementsByName(groupName);
    for (i = 0; i < radios.length; i++) {
        if (radios[i].checked) {
            return radios[i].value;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
function check() {
    for(var i=1;i<=max;i++) {
        //console.log(i,getCheckedValue('Q'+i));
        aux[i-1] = getCheckedValue('Q'+i);
    }
    console.log(aux);
}
```

​
**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/PpqDm/)**.

Answer (score 1):

<s>Don't use radio buttons, use checkboxes instead (checked=yes, unchecked=no). Then you can iterate your checkboxes freely, and see what's checked and not.</s> Striked out, OP needs the difference between "yes", "no" and "no answer".

---

After some extensive coding (my JS is rusty) I came up with the following:

```
<form name=form1 id=form1 action="index.php">
    <p>Question 1</p>
    <label><input type="radio" name="Q1" value="yes">Yes</label>
    <label><input type="radio" name="Q1" value="no">No</label>

    <p>Question 2</p>
    <label><input type="radio" name="Q2" value="yes">Yes</label>
    <label><input type="radio" name="Q2" value="no">No</label>

    <p>Question 3</p>
    <label><input type="radio" name="Q3" value="yes">Yes</label>
    <label><input type="radio" name="Q3" value="no">No</label>

    <button id="go">Go!</button>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
    check = function (e) {
        e.preventDefault(); //Don't submit!
        var result = [];
        var form = document.getElementById("form1");
        for (var i = 1; typeof(form["Q" + i]) != "undefined"; i++) {
            for (var j = 0; j < form["Q" + i].length; j++) {
                if (form["Q" + i][j].checked) {
                    result.push(form["Q" + i][j].name + " " + form["Q" + i][j].value);
                }
            }
        }
        console.log(result);
    }

    button = document.getElementById("go");
    button.onclick = check;

</script>
```

Triggered by clicking the "Go!" button.

---

The point is using the string concatenation of "Q" and i to get to "Q1" "Q2" etc.

Comment: So what then prevents some fool from checking yes and no for every question?

Comment: @j08691: Only one checkbox, checked = yes, and unchecked = no. `[x] Question 1`, `[ ] Question 2` etc.

Comment: @Truth They have to be radiobuttons. Because I need to know the difference between the value="NO" and if there is not any answer.

Comment: Don't use checkboxes, use radio buttons as this is what they were intended for.

Comment: Indeed that is a different case. I have a different solution for you then, please wait:

Comment: @j08691: Radio buttons were intended for **a selection from a list**, for instance, a multi-answer test: "What's 2+2? 1. 2, 2. 4, 3. 6, 4. 8" Select the correct answer. A checkbox is used for a "true/false" selection, which seems to be his case. He stated however that there is a difference between "yes, no and no answer", meaning I can't use checkboxes as this is a **3 way selection**. Please don't say things you can't backup with some reliable sources.

Comment: @Truth - Spare me your condescending attitude. Radio buttons are used for selecting zero or one item from a group. Period. Checkboxes are used for selecting zero or more items from a group. So while a single checkbox might get the job done, it is not the proper UI to present to a user, nor is it the proper choice for this question.